# Best practice for sending long emails with PHP

Tags: php, email

For one of my customers, I need to be able to send long emails with data gathered in a contact form.

By "long", I mean 2000 characters, in Japanese which means that characters might be double-byte encoded (page encoding set to UTF-8, but unsure what happen in POST).

We were first using a mailer developed in-house (way before my time) which was using the PHP mail() function and we found mojibake every 495 or so characters.

Looking a little bit in the documentation, I saw that the RFC 5322 has a limitation at 998 characters and with the double-byte encoding for Japanese characters, that seems to be the cause of the problem.

I switched to PHPMailer (my personal solution of choice) and the problem seems to be solved.

But, I'd love to learn what are the actual best practice in the domain.

Anything ?

Comment: Why not send CSV or XML instead?

Comment: That 998 character limit you mentioned is for single lines of text inside the email body. All you have to do, is split it into multiple lines in that case ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php#74423 (Not sure atm whether chuck_split is multibyte safe ... if not, you have to go look for an alternative that is.)

Comment: @CBroe : yes, the thing is, the way the code was written, the new lines where scrapped... the whole text-area was transmitted as a single line...
Not perfect code actually

Comment: @Justinas Wrapping the text in a attachment ? Yes, that would work. Hadn't thought of that

Comment: My Solution, Use imageMagic to convert text to image (png) add this in image tag of your html and done. send it with any mailer

Comment: @AnandG Why not, that would work. Not a big fan of storing text as image though